# how to apply show() and hide() jquery function to css display property

Tags: jquery, css, hide, show

I have a side menu for my project. I am not using bootstrap templates. Rather for learning purposes, I am developing my own sidemenu.
Now what is happening is that to show and hide the menu, I am using jquery `hide()` and `show()` functions.
But doing so makes the menu look little weird when hiding or showing.
For example you can see this fiddle(the delay is purposely set to 2s so that you can observe the weird change). https://jsfiddle.net/6v25oggm/3/
Can anyone help me on this.?

Comment: what problem is there?

Comment: Sir @AlivetoDie, if you have seen the fiddle, there you would see that when sidemenu is clicked, it opens the menu like it is creating it and not like it is opening it.

Comment: I have tried show, hide, fadein, fadeout, fadetoggle like function on display block and none, but it is not effective.

Comment: Try using Jquery .toggle() methods. That will help you

Comment: `toggle()` also not effective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code can be greatly reduced using `slideToggle` and some simple logic for checking if the `a` has a sub-menu next to it.

Please check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vxaoryg3/2/

Comment: I have just fixed some issues with the other open sub-menus not collapsing properly, using the `not` method

Comment: Thank you @tigerdi Sir. Your solution worked with minor adjustments.!

Comment: No problem. Forgot to mention that you can now remove a lot of those unnecessary ids on the html

Answer (score 2):

You should use `slideUp` and `slideDown`.

While the `slide` functions only affect the height of an element, the `show/hide` functions affect both height and width.

See **[this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vt6q645q/)** in action

Comment: Thank you @trichetriche Sir for your contribution.!

Answer (score 1):

using *tigerdi*'s suggestion & *trichetriche*'s solutions (implementation)

**updated**

```
$('.sidebar-menu li').click(function(e) 
{
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).siblings().find('.sidebar-sub-menu').slideUp();
    $(this).find('.sidebar-sub-menu').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: This would slide up the `.sidebar-sub-menu` when clicking on the nested `li`. Add in `e.stopPropagation();` to stop the event from bubbling up.